# What type of variable declaration is this in java

Tags: java

```
class FreshJuice {
   enum FreshJuiceSize{ SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE }
   FreshJuiceSize size;
}
```

What type of variable is `size` ?

Is `FreshJuiceSize size;` a shorhand way of declaring `size` as a instance variable ?

Comment: What would be the "longhand" form?

Comment: It is just an enum type.

Comment: that FreshJuiceSize might as well be renamed to just Size since it is already encapsulated in FreshJuice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `size` is a member variable with type `FreshJuiceSize` (an `enum` constrained to the 3 values you defined).

Perhaps what makes it look unusual is the absence of an access modifier: `public`, `protected` or `private`.  For a member with no declared access modifier, it is "package-private", meaning that other classes within the same package may access it, but classes outside the package may not.  The Java documentation on [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) describes this.

Comment: Would that be a correct rule of thumb for `enum`.More than 2 distinct values use enum , else use boolean

Comment: @user2650277 I would say no for your question. Enum also makes naming meaningful. Imagine enum gender. If you were to use boolean, does `true` means male or female?

Comment: @user2650277, sometimes even if there are only 2 distinct values, it can be nice to use an `enum` to make code more readable.  That way, you can pass the more descriptive `enum` values in method calls instead of trying to remember what `true` and `false` mean for that particular method call.  You also have the capability to implement custom methods on the `enum`.  It takes more code to set it up compared to using a `boolean`, so it's a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The variable type of size is `enum FreshJuiceSize`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is FreshJuiceSize size; a shorhand way of declaring size as a instance variable ?

You are just creating a reference of type `FreshJuiceSize` which is an enum with a set of ***predefined constants***. There is no "short hand" or "long hand".

Answer (score 0):

Size is variable of FreshJuiceSize type
FreshJuiceSize is an enumeration so that size takes only one of { SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE } set

Comment: There are no integers involved.

Comment: [Here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Enum.java/?v=source) you can find the source code of Enum class, position of enumeration variable is int, Enum itself just mapping them.

Comment: That's implementation details. It shouldn't be relevant to the average user.

Answer (score 0):

FeshJuice is a class - most likely private - not main -  judging by the lack of public class classname declaration - FreshJuiceSize is the enum name (similar to the name of an array), and FreshJuiceSize size; declares the variable size to be a member (I forget the term) of FreshJuiceSize